# Caused by: java.io.IOException: NetworkError,Network error while getting auth token

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-api, ioexception, general-network-error

Below is the Manifest file .I am trying to get conected with parse ...but just after succussful gradle build I get the below mentioned error ..and I am not able to login or signup on the  app.Please help

```
      <application
                android:name=".Application"
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
                    android:value="" />
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
                    android:value="" />
                <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
                <!--
                     The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
                     (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
                     Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
                     You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
                     sign the APK for publishing.
                     You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
                -->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

                <activity
                    android:name=".MapsActivity"
                    android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name=".Welcome_Activity">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity"></activity>
                <activity android:name=".Login_Activity"></activity>
                <activity android:name=".DispatchActivity"></activity>

            </application>

        </manifest>


********************************************************************************    

    Error

    03-15 04:56:17.262 1774-1774/? D/Finsky: [1] ContentSyncService$5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
    03-15 04:56:18.638 501-516/? I/ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{52b00020 u0 com.google.android.gms/.checkin.CheckinService}
    03-15 04:56:20.182 814-988/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() failed. Status NETWORK_ERROR, Account: <ELLIDED:-1479263863>, App: com.google.android.talk, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.peopleapi.readwrite https://www.googleapis.com/auth/hangouts https://www.googleapis.com/auth/identity.plus.page.impersonation  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.native
    03-15 04:56:20.182 1723-3194/? E/Babel: Network error while getting auth token
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel: cdd: Cannot get auth token
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at g.a(Unknown Source)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at ccw.a(SourceFile:3105)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at ccw.a(SourceFile:1149)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at dax.a(SourceFile:4333)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at dax.a(SourceFile:1420)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cwm.a(SourceFile:489)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cwm.a(SourceFile:2462)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cvv.a(SourceFile:4352)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cdk.b(SourceFile:105)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cdh.d(SourceFile:340)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cdi.run(SourceFile:90)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:  Caused by: java.io.IOException: NetworkError
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at eld.b(Unknown Source)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at eld.a(Unknown Source)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at eld.b(Unknown Source)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at g.a(Unknown Source)
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at ccw.a(SourceFile:3105) 
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at ccw.a(SourceFile:1149) 
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at dax.a(SourceFile:4333) 
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at dax.a(SourceFile:1420) 
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cwm.a(SourceFile:489) 
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cwm.a(SourceFile:2462) 
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cvv.a(SourceFile:4352) 
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cdk.b(SourceFile:105) 
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cdh.d(SourceFile:340) 
    03-15 04:56:20.186 1723-3194/? E/Babel:     at cdi.run(SourceFile:90) 
    03-15 04:56:24.254 814-817/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 25% free 4214K/5568K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 23ms
    03-15 04:56:26.682 501-545/? D/ConnectivityService: handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=0, published condition=0
    03-15 04:56:30.190 814-987/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() failed. Status NETWORK_ERROR, Account: <ELLIDED:-1479263863>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: AndroidCheckInServer
    03-15 04:56:30.194 1082-3312/? W/CheckinRequestBuilder: error reading account token
    03-15 04:56:30.194 1082-3312/? W/CheckinRequestBuilder: java.io.IOException: NetworkError
```

Comment: Could someone please help

Comment: How did you solve this issue ?